# Copy message text in android 7

Tags: sms, copy-paste

In my past phone (Android 6) I could long tap a message and sow "Copy" context menu.
Now in Android 7 I see only some strange icons on taping a message.
[image: screenshot]
Could somebody advice how I can copy message text?

Answer (score 1):

- [image] This icon on the top means **copy**. Pressing this button
  should copy the text to your clipboard.
- [image: List item] This icon means **share**. After pressing this icon, you shall be prompted with multiple apps on your device that allow you to share this message.
- [image: List item]This icon means **forward**. When you press this icon, you'll be able to directly forward this message to somebody else.
- [image: List item]This icon means **info**. Pressing this icon will show you more information about the message. (e.g. sender, server, etc..)
- [image: List item]This icon stand for **delete**. By pressing this icon will the message be deleted.

Comment: But how do you copy only a specific portion of text from a message and not the entire msg?